# RxWeb Reactive Form Validators: Don't Validate if Form is Empty

Tags: angular, vue.js, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

I am using [Reactive Form Validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) in VueJS and have all the validation working nicely. However, I wish to disable validation when the form is empty. When users load the page, the form is already complaining about bad input which is not appealing.

[image: Example]

Code:

```
  <v-text-field
    required
   label="Username"
    v-model="user_form.props.username"
    :error-messages="user_form.controls.username.errorMessage"
    outlined
  />
  <v-text-field
    label="Email"
    v-model="user_form.props.email"
    :error-messages="user_form.controls.email.errorMessage"
    outlined
  />
  <v-text-field
    v-model="user_form.props.password"
    type="password"
    :error-messages="user_form.controls.password.errorMessage"
    label="Password"
    required
    outlined
  />

import {email, alpha, minLength, required } from "@rxweb/reactive-forms"
export class UserForm {
  @alpha()
  @minLength({value: 5})
  @required()
  username: string

  @minLength({value: 5})
  @required()
  password: string

  @minLength({value: 5})
  @required()
  @email()
  email: string

  constructor() {
    this.username = ''
    this.password = ''
    this.email = ''
  }
}
```

I have tried setting :error-messages to a custom function that returns empty string when the field is empty. That works just fine but the field is still in an error state. Surely there must be a better way?

Thanks